# C code for this ARM code

Tags: c, arm

Hi can you help me get C code for this ARM code:

('...' means further instructions)

```
ADR r1, TABLE

CMP r0, #TABLEMAX

LDRLS pc, [r1,r0,LSL #2]

... ; statementsD

B EXIT

TABLE DCD L0

DCD L1

...

DCD LN

L0 ... ; statements0

B EXIT

L1 ... ; statements1

B EXIT

...

LN ... ; statementsN

EXIT ...
```

Comment: No, I can't. Nobody can - it's unreadable. And even if somebody could, he wouldn't want to given that you put absolutely no research effort into this.

Comment: Perhaps something like [this](http://www.ethernut.de/en/documents/arm-inline-asm.html)?

Comment: I'm sorry if it's not readable.. its lost it's alignment when i copied here.

Answer (score 1):

This was a switch statement in the original C code, something like:

```
switch (a) {
case 0: 
    ... // statements 0
break;
case 1:
    ... // statements 1
break;
...
case TABLE_MAX /* (maybe TABLE_MAX -1) */ :
    ...  // statements N
break;
default:
    ...  // statements D
break;
```

}

Where a = r0.

More recent versions of the ARM architecture in the Thumb-2 ISA include the 'Table Branch' instructions TBB, TBH for code size reductions of this particular case.

Comment: +1 It can also be an array of function pointers, or gcc's [Labels as Values](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html).  Those may match the assembler closer, but in principal this is correct.

Comment: 'Labels as Values' how did they come up with that? I still think the range check and default case at the beginning make this much more likely to be a switch statement.

Comment: I don't think it is compiled 'C'.  It is hand coded ARM assembler and he wanted a translation to 'C'.  Maybe for another CPU.  If it was to understand the ARM assembler, then some of my suggestion work.  A good ARM compiler will make similar machine code with your 'C'. [not thumb2, but traditional ARM].